# MySQL - min_word_length 2 or 3 - need a count

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I am trying to decide whether to set min_word_length to be 2 or 3 on my new MySQL instance, so i figure if I count the number of 2 letter words in the column to be indexed it will give an indication of the right answer.

So, question is, is it possible using a SQL query to count the number two letter words within a column?

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but could you try

```
SELECT SUM(
CASE WHEN yourColumn REGEXP '[[:<:]][a-zA-Z]{2}[[:>:]]'
THEN 1 
ELSE 0 END
) AS matches 
FROM ...
```

Although I think, that it might only count if a 2-character-word is in a row, not how many times in one row.

UPDATE: Tested and it works like I thought, so please just ignore this answer.

Answer (score -1):

The LEN() function returns the length of the value in a text field.

```
SELECT LEN(column_name) FROM table_name
```

The COUNT(*) function returns the number of records in a table:

```
SELECT COUNT(column_name) FROM table_name
```

So your query should be something like this :

```
SELECT COUNT(column_name) FROM table_name
WHERE LEN(column_name)=2
```

UPDATE:

Ok sorry I guess I misunderstood you. In the case you want it I'm afraid there is no build in functions to do what you want it to do. So you have to make a function on your own. Something like this should work:

```
            CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[WordCount] ( @InputString VARCHAR(4000) ) 
            RETURNS INT
            AS
            BEGIN

            DECLARE @Index          INT
            DECLARE @Char           CHAR(1)
            DECLARE @PrevChar       CHAR(1)
            DECLARE @WordCount      INT
            DECLARE @CharCount      INT

            SET @Index = 1
            SET @WordCount = 0

            WHILE @Index <= LEN(@InputString)
            BEGIN
            SET @Char     = SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Index, 1)
            SET @CharCount = @CharCount + 1
            SET @PrevChar = CASE WHEN @Index = 1 THEN ' '
                    ELSE SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Index - 1, 1)
            END


            IF @PrevChar = ' '
                SET @CharCount = 1
            END


            IF @Char = ' ' AND @CharCount < 3 AND @CharCount > 1
                SET @WordCount = @WordCount + 1

            SET @Index = @Index + 1
            END

            RETURN @WordCount

            END
```

Now I have not tested it so you have to test it on your own but it should work. It will return all 2 letter words in the selected string. To get the 3 letters words just change

```
IF @Char = ' ' AND @CharCount < 4 AND @CharCount > 2
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: It's about a full-text-search. So he most likely wants to have a count of 2-character-words in columns with content like "foo ba bar fo foooooo".

Comment: @tombom Exactly right - I need to know how many two letter words WITHIN the column, not the col as a whole - thanks for taking the time tho